# ocaml type definition contains ellipsis

Tags: ocaml, ellipsis

I'm reading some Ocaml project's source code and I'm new to Ocaml.I'm confused in the following code,which is a some kind of type definition in a .ml file.

```
type event = Event.t = ..
```

What's the meaning of '..' in the code,I searched the manual but get nothing. And in the event.mli,the type definition is :

```
type t = ..
type event = t = ..
```

Any help is appreciated,thanks.

Comment: They are open datatypes.

Take a look [here](https://sites.google.com/site/ocamlopen/)

Comment: @pdexter I can't open this link,possibly because of our nation's policy,I'm come from China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its new "extensible variant types". See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec251 for details.

You can declare a empty extensible variant type with

```
type t = ..
```

then later you can add new constructors like

```
type t += Foo | Bar of int
```

You can add constructors to extensible variants more than once places of programs.  Instead, you cannot enjoy non-exhaustiveness check at pattern match, which is available for normal variants.

`type event = t = ..` declares an alias `event` of already existing extensible type `t`. `= ..` is required to make the new type also extensible.

```
type event = t = ..
type event += Poo  (* you cannot do this if type event = t *)
```

### Note

Extensible variant types may be useful when:

- You do not want to fix the set of the constructors.
- You feel constructors are rather loosely related each other and see no benefit to declare them in one place.

For example, the type of various errors of an application is a good candidate to define as an EVT: an app may fail due to a network issue, an auth failure, disk full and so on.  They are unrelated with each other and come from many parts of the app.  In that case you may want to define the type `error` as an EVT:

```
(* module Error *)
type t = ..

(* module Web *)
type Error.t += Http of int (* ex. 404 *)

(* module Tempfile *)
type Error.t += Diskfull of Path.t

(* module ErrorHandler *)
let print_error (e : Error.t) = match e with
  | Web.HTTP stat -> ...
  | Tempfile.Diskfull path -> ...
  | ...
```

You may notice it looks like exceptions, actually EVT is generalized version of exception.

Comment: Thanks,and I still have some more questions on this.1st,what is the meaning of having '**extensible variant types**',i.e.what circumstance does EVT usually be used for ; 2nd,when I test `type event = t = ..`,utop raises **Error: Parse error: "private" or "{" or "|" or [constructor_declarations] expected after "=" (in [type_kind])**

Comment: For 1, I extended my answer.  For 2, my guess is that utop's parser does not know this new syntax.

Comment: **For 2**,I've tested use ocamlopt to build a test.ml containing such double '=' definition of EVT and totally succeed. **For 1**,you give me a great example,which also implies that I should explicitly list the module where this constructor defined in when I want to use an EVT constructor,like Error.Web.Http rather than Error.Http.Thanks again!

Comment: It seems utop has its own OCaml parser which is a bit outdated. (I do not use utop...

Answer (score 2):

It is an extensible variant type. It's a variant to which you can add new cases in other places than the definition point. For example you can add to this `event` yourself in your code by writing:

```
type event += 
  | Mouse_move of int * int
  | Mouse_down of int * int
```

Extensible variant types are part of the language since 4.02 and are described in the manual in [this section](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec251).